# PKCS#7 CMS - Message digest calculation process

Tags: asn.1, pkcs#7, der, ber

i'm studying RFC 5652 in order to know exactly how to encode/decode PKCS#7 ASN.1 data.

I don't understand how one can create a signature when the field "signedAttrs" is present:

> The result of the message digest calculation process depends on
> whether the signedAttrs field is present.  When the field is absent,
> the result is just the message digest of the content as described
> above.  When the field is present, however, the result is the message
> digest of the complete DER encoding of the SignedAttrs value
> contained in the signedAttrs field.  Since the SignedAttrs value,
> when present, must contain the content-type and the message-digest
> attributes, those values are indirectly included in the result.

By reading the above text I get confused: SignedAttrs field contains message-digest and content-type values but message-digest can be present once calculated and the digest has to be calculated on:

**eContent OCTET STRING** + **full DER encoding of SignedAttrs field (Containing message-digest field).**

In the example below there is a PKCS#7 Signed data structure where the envelopedData content field value is being signed + the signed attributes. Where
does exactly the messageDigest value come from?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two different message-digests in CMS algorithm:

- First message-digest is a **signed attribute** which contains digest only of the encapsulated content being signed.
- Second one is **that will be signed by the signature algorithm**. This message-digest contains digest which is calculated by the specific algorithm:

  The input to the message-digest algorithm is **the Content**. In case of absent signed attributes, the digest of current input (current input = the Content) will be created and returned as a resulting message digest. Otherwise, if signed attributes are present, then the digest of **the Content** is calculated and added to the signed attributes list (as Message-digest signed attribute) and then the digest of all signed attributes is calculated. So the content is indirectly included in the result